# Error al guardar una Imagen en JPA - JAVA

Tags: java, web, jpa, java-ee, eclipselink

Tengo un formulario de **Alumnos** que al intentar guardar me sale error en la **imagen** ,porfavor me pueden ayudar, saludos

**Clase Alumno**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Alumno.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Alumno a")
public class Alumno implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name="IdAlumno")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private String idAlumno;

private String apellido;

private int celular;

private String correo;

private String direccion;

private int dni;


@Column(name="fech_nac")
private String fechNac;

@Column(name="fech_reg")
private String fechReg;

@Lob
private byte[] foto;

private String grado;

private String nombre;

private String sexo;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="alumnoBean",cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Nota> notas;

public Alumno() {
}

public String getIdAlumno() {
    return this.idAlumno;
}

public void setIdAlumno(String idAlumno) {
    this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return this.apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public int getCelular() {
    return this.celular;
}

public void setCelular(int celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return this.correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return this.direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public int getDni() {
    return this.dni;
}

public void setDni(int dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getFechNac() {
    return this.fechNac;
}

public void setFechNac(String fechNac) {
    this.fechNac = fechNac;
}

public String getFechReg() {
    return this.fechReg;
}

public void setFechReg(String fechReg) {
    this.fechReg = fechReg;
}

public byte[] getFoto() {
    return this.foto;
}

public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public String getGrado() {
    return this.grado;
}

public void setGrado(String grado) {
    this.grado = grado;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return this.sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public List<Nota> getNotas() {
    return this.notas;
}

public void setNotas(List<Nota> notas) {
    this.notas = notas;
}

public Nota addNota(Nota nota) {
    getNotas().add(nota);
    nota.setAlumnoBean(this);

    return nota;
}

public Nota removeNota(Nota nota) {
    getNotas().remove(nota);
    nota.setAlumnoBean(null);

    return nota;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Alumno [idAlumno=" + idAlumno + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", celular=" + celular + ", correo=" + correo
            + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", dni=" + dni + ", fechNac=" + fechNac + ", fechReg=" + fechReg
            + ", foto=" + Arrays.toString(foto) + ", grado=" + grado + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", sexo=" + sexo
            + ", notas=" + notas + "]";
}
```

}

**Controlador Alumno**

> En esta parte se declara todos los metodos del mantenimiento **(eliminar ,actualizar, editar, litar)**
> Estos metodos estan referenciados con JPA PARA PODER AUTOMATIZAR nuestra aplicacion

```
public class AlumnoModel {

public void GuardarDatos(Alumno a) {
    
    EntityManager manager=null;
    try {
        
        manager=JPA_UTIL.getEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(a); // Genera el JPQL(consulta sql) internamente
        manager.flush();// Enviar en cola(pueden haber varios SQL)
        manager.getTransaction().commit(); // Envia a la BD
    } catch (Exception e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        
    }finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
}
```

**Entidad Alumno**

> En esta parte de codigo del guardado le paso de parametro la imagen en byte eso estaria bien

```
 public class AlumnoDAO {

private AlumnoModel m = new AlumnoModel();
private Alumno a = new Alumno();
public Integer totalRegistro;
//private String mensaje = "";

 private static final Logger LOGGER =Logger.getLogger("com.sistema.colegio.Dao.AlumnoDAO");

public int InsertarDatos(String idAlumno, String nombre, String apellido, int dni, int celular, String fechNac,
        String fechReg, String grado, String sexo, String direccion, String correo,byte[] foto) {
    int rpta=0;
    try {
        a.setIdAlumno(idAlumno);
        a.setNombre(nombre);
        a.setApellido(apellido);
        a.setDni(dni);
        a.setCelular(celular);
        a.setFechNac(fechNac);
        a.setFechReg(fechReg);
        a.setGrado(grado);
        a.setSexo(sexo);
        a.setDireccion(direccion);
        a.setCorreo(correo);
        a.setFoto(foto);
        m.GuardarDatos(a);

    //  mensaje = "EXITO! SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE";
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Proceso exitoso");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    //  mensaje = "ERROR NO SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE";
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error no se guardo");
    }
    return rpta;
}
}
```

**Convertir Imagen en Byte**

```
 public class ImagenConver {

 public static Image imagen(Icon icon) {
    int w=icon.getIconWidth();
    int h=icon.getIconHeight();
    GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd=ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    GraphicsConfiguration gc=gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage bi=gc.createCompatibleImage(w,h);
    Graphics2D g=bi.createGraphics();
    icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}

public static byte[] tipoimagen(Image imge) {
    BufferedImage bi=new 
   BufferedImage(imge.getWidth(null),imge.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
    Graphics g=bi.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(imge,0,0,null);
    g.dispose();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", stream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImagenConver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "error de imagen", ex);
    }
    return stream.toByteArray();
    
}
}
```

**Formulario Alumno**

> En esta parte del codigo es donde me marca  el error  de la imagen al convertirla  me podrian ayudar porfavor

```
     protected void actionPerformedBtnAgregar(ActionEvent arg0) {
       if (txtId.getText().equals("") || txtNombre.getText().equals("") || 
        txtApellido.getText().equals("")
            || txtDni.getText().equals("") || txtCelular.getText().equals("") || 
        txtFecha.getText().equals("")
            || txtReg.getText().equals("") || txtDireccion.getText().equals("") || 
        txtCorreo.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "COMPLETAR TODOS LOS CAMPOS DEL FORMULARIO", "ERROR",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        String idAlumno = txtId.getText();
        String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
        String apellido = txtApellido.getText();
        int dni = Integer.parseInt(txtDni.getText());
        int celular = Integer.parseInt(txtCelular.getText());
        String fechNac = txtFecha.getText();
        String fechReg = txtReg.getText();
        String grado = cboGrado.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (rdbtHombre.isSelected()) {
            gender = "H";
        } else if (rdbtnM.isSelected()) {
            gender = "M";
        }
        String sexo = gender;
        
        String direccion = txtDireccion.getText();
        
        String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
        Image image = ImagenConver.imagen(FOTO.getIcon());
        ImagenConver.tipoimagen(image);
        int opcion = al.InsertarDatos(idAlumno, nombre, apellido, dni, celular, fechNac, fechReg, 
   grado, sexo,
                direccion, correo,image);
        
        if(opcion ==0) {
            try {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se Registro Corectamente", "", 
   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                limpiar();
                bloquear();
                btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Registar !!", "", 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se considera una mala practica el guardar una imagen directamente en la base de datos , podrías guardar esa imagen en alguna carpeta dentro del proyecto y despues guardar la ruta en la BD como un String .

En java hay muy buenas librerias para manejar este problema ,
hechale un vistazo java.io y java.nio

te dejo un ejemplo propio con spring para que puedas hacerte una idea.

```
/**
     *Metodo de tipo POST que guarda un cliente en la base de datos , si este no tiene id nulo ,
     * se creara un nuevo registro ,
     *Si la variable foto es distinto de nulo actualizara la foto del cliente.
     * @param cliente
     * @param foto
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/guardarCliente")
    public String guardarCliente(@Valid Cliente cliente,
            BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status,
            RedirectAttributes flash,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile foto) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            
            log.info("Hubo un error de validacion en el formulario cliente.");
            
            return "agregarCliente";
        }

        if (!foto.isEmpty()) {

            if (cliente.getId() != null
                    && cliente.getId() > 0
                    && cliente.getFoto() != null
                    && cliente.getFoto().length() > 0) {

              this.subirArchivoServicio.borrarImagen(cliente.getFoto());

            }
            
            String nombreArchivoUnico = null;
            
            try {
                nombreArchivoUnico = this.subirArchivoServicio.copiarImagen(foto);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.info(ex.toString());
                log.info("Problemas al subir el archivo ... ");
            }
            
            flash.addFlashAttribute("success", "Has subido correctamente : " + nombreArchivoUnico);
            cliente.setFoto(nombreArchivoUnico);
        }
        
        
        this.clienteServicio.guardarCliente(cliente);

        status.setComplete();

        flash.addFlashAttribute("info", "El cliente ha sido guardado con exito");

        return "redirect:/cliente/listadoClientes";
    }
```

Y el metodo copiarImagen

```
@Override
    public String copiarImagen(MultipartFile archivo) throws IOException {

        String nombreArchivoUnico = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + archivo.getOriginalFilename();

        Path rutaRaiz = obtenerRutaAbsoluta(nombreArchivoUnico);

        Path rutaAbsoluta = rutaRaiz.toAbsolutePath();

        log.info("Se ha guardado la imagen en : " + rutaAbsoluta.toString());

        Files.copy(archivo.getInputStream(), rutaAbsoluta);

        return nombreArchivoUnico;

    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado saludos.